# appending input elements into the dom based on the value selected with help of java script?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

```
<html>
<body>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       function showSelected(val)
         {
    document.getElementById('selectedResult').innerHTML = "The selected number    
    is - " + val;
         }
      </script>
         <div id='selectedResult'></div>
           <select name='test' onChange='showSelected(this.value)'> 
            <option value='1'>one </option>
            <option value='2'>two </option>
          </select>
```

hi i need a help, when i select "one" in the drop down, the script need to display one text box(input field) in a table, when i select "two" in the drop down the script need to display two text boxs((input fields) in a table? how to achive this plz help me?

Comment: Aside from missing a < on your closing div, works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/mPp2r/

Comment: ya. by mistake i missed the open tag, instead of the text i need to display text box.as like my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text as well as the value of a select box, you should refer to the selected option rather than just the select box:

```
<select name='test' onchange='showSelected(this[this.selectedIndex].value)'>
```

or

```
<select name='test' onchange='showSelected(this[this.selectedIndex].text)'>
```

other than that, your code works fine.

As the question has been clarified to appending input elements into the dom based on the value selected:

```
function showSelected(num) {
  var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    docFrag.appendChild(input);
  }

  var selectedResult = document.getElementById('selectedResult');
  while(selectedResult.firstChild) selectedResult.removeChild(selectedResult.firstChild);
  selectedResult.appendChild(docFrag);
}
```

With another clarification to the question:

```
function showSelected(num) {
  var tr = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>'),
      table = jQuery('<table><tbody></tbody></table>'),
      tbody = table.find('tbody');

  for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    tbody.append( tr.clone() );
  }

  jQuery('#selectedResult').empty().append(table);
}
```

Comment: steveukx, thanks for your reply., plz help me to build text boxs dynamically based on the drop down selection. i dont want to display the text.

Comment: do you mean a text box as in an input field, a textarea for multi-line input, or a new element on the page?

Comment: ya i mean the text box, when i select "one" in the drop down the script should display one text box(input field) in the page and when i select "two" from the drop down it should display two text box(input field) in the page.

Comment: great steveukx, thanks a lot... this is what i expected. sorry for the poor question... can u plz help to remove the down rating.

Comment: var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
 var table=document.createElement('TABLE');
  table.border='0';
  tar.appendChild(table);
 var tbdy=document.createElement('TBODY');
  table.appendChild(tbdy);
  for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) 
     {
   var tr=document.createElement('TR');
   tbdy.appendChild(tr);
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    tr.appendChild(input);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    docFrag.appendChild(table);
     }
  
can u plz correct this to add the input field in table

Comment: If you need to make something more complex than just a couple of elements, I'd recommend either setting the innerHTML of the element (if you don't need immediate references to the elements and are ok to overwrite the entire thing) or use a template system / dom framework like jQuery.

Comment: while(selectedResult.firstChild) selectedResult.removeChild ; here i found one issure steveukx., when i select one in the drop down at very first time, it faild display one text field., but if i select "two" first & if i go with "one" its working fine. what is the problem?

Comment: Are you using the latests example above? That doesn't include the while statement, it uses jQuery's .empty method to clear the container instead.

Comment: If you're able to include jQuery, use the latest one - it will make your code a lot cleaner when using larger templates... if not, you could always replace the while(...) line with `selectedResult.innerHTML = '';` to empty its contents.